# С# and mysql

Tags: c#

При подключении к бд выдаёт такую ошибку [link text](http://joxi.ru/nXBzUtg5CbD-a9r03ls)

```
Код:
    ataTable GetComm()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mysb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            mysb.Server = "5.175.169.75";
            mysb.Database = "pw";
            mysb.UserID = "root";
            mysb.Password = "1111";
            mysb.Port = 3306;

        string queryString = @"SELECT Null FROM users";

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = mysb.ConnectionString;
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(queryString ,con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                        dt.Load(dr);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return dt;
```

Comment: Роман, так вы же у MySqlConnectionStringBuilder  не указали ни сервера, ни название БД, ни логин и пароль.

Comment: Указал я, просто отсюда вырезал, чтобы не палить данные от mysql

Comment: До `SQL`'я тут дело не доходит. Похоже что проблема в ваших "безпалевных" данных.

Comment: данные ввожу правильные, через пма(пхпмайадмин) захожу в базу

Comment: @Роман1211 вы вот хотите, чтоб вам помогли, а сами из каких-то параноидальных соображений прячете данные. Ради любопытства посмотрел аналогичные вопросы на StackOverflow - везде говорят, что проблема именно в тех данных, которые вы так упорно прячете. Проверяйте их. А "лечение по фотографии" дело бесполезное

Comment: добавил данные, прошу помочь

Comment: мне, например, указанный сервер по телнету отвечает: 

    Host '<мой IP>' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

вы через PMA установленный на вашей машине подключаетесь? или он на том же сервере?

возможно мускуль настроен только на локальные подключения